# Mining Performance of AMD Radeon Pro Duo

Tags: mining, gpu, hashrate, benchmark

I would like to evaluate the purchase of that GPU for Ethereum Mining. Does someone already have benchmarks?

Comment: yeah we need more details... and have you tried mining on 15.12 and earlier drivers?

Comment: Have a look at http://youtu.be/6bSjp-FKweo for an interesting test.

Comment: I am getting 59M/h reported but effective is way lower. Not sure why. Have been running dorp 48h and difference is about half. Tested both claymore and genoil ethermine

Comment: use the firepro driver for 60+mhash

Comment: @user4447 60+mh with <300w?

Answer (score 7):

We just received ours ... 42m/h atm @ 370w ... mainly due to the 16.5.3 driver ...

Comment: On what OS? It's lower than expected... How much did you pay for it?

Comment: this is a lot worse than expected. where you able to tweak it @bitsbetrippin?

Answer (score 5):

No benchmark looks to be available and i think it's due to the fact that this card looks to be very expensive and quantity is limited. However, the pro duo seems to be a radeon fury x2. So you can imagine that, as fury x looks to be around 30MH/s, this card would be 60MH/s. However for the same hashrate you can use 3 radeon r9 290 with some oc and it will cost you less than $600 instead of $1800 for the pro duo.
Hashrate is more a matter of memory interface speed than a mater of GPU power. AMD indicated a 4096 bits memory interface. This is huge. So you may have a very good hashrate. But is it valuable in front of multiple small cards? I don't know. Still power consumption will be lower with only 300W. So until you try, we won't know.